# Google App Engine MemcacheService.delete(key, millisNoReAdd) doesn't always hold out concurrent putters

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In my GAE application (java 8 standard env) we make extensive use of MemcacheService.  In putting some concurrency control mechanisms in place I've come to discover that using [MemcacheService.delete(Object key, long millisNoReAdd)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.html#delete-java.lang.Object-long-) does not always hold out concurrent users of the cache from putting that same key within the millisNoReAdd delay.

I am using 1000ms as the millisNoReAdd and through logging I can frequently see a key getting re-added to memcache well within that 1000ms.  Sometimes it's only 10's of millis after the delete, sometimes 100's.  I'm not sure if there's an unreasonable lower limit to expect google to be able to handle concurrent operations in memcache due to rpc calls or not, but the documentation seems pretty straightforward that using the delete with millisNoReAdd should prevent adding the same key for that duration, period.  We're using the regular MemcacheService, not AsyncMemcacheService fyi.

Our overall caching strategy is that reads from the datastore will cache entities to help subsequent reads, and writes to the datastore will remove entities from the cache.  It's pretty basic, but seems to be the most foolproof approach for GAE.  We did try caching records on writes as well, but then ran into too many race conditions leading to stale cache data.  So deleting entities on a write seems to be the cleanest approach despite the first reader after that paying the penalty to re-cache the entity.

In trying multiple things to figure this millisNoReAdd issue out (or work around it), I've settled on this for deleting from memcache (pseudocode):

```
MemcacheService.putAll(keyValuesMap, expiration, SetPolicy.SET_ALWAYS);
MemcacheService.deleteAll(keyValuesMap.keySet(), 1000);
```

I have the putAll() in there because the documentation is not clear on what deleteAll() will do if a key is not found... does it still lock out that key for the millisNoReAdd or does nothing happen at all?  Putting the putAll() up front ensures the key is in there to be deleted so I don't have to worry about that question.  Not my favorite hack, but it did seem to lessen the issues during the millisNoReadd duration.  The 1000ms is there to give the actual datastore write rpc time to complete so that by the time the millisNoReAdd delay is up, any readers should be getting the freshest data directly from datastore before caching it.  Any readers during that duration could possibly get stale data directly from datastore but there's only so much you can do.

The concurrent putters that should be held out but not always are are using SetPolicy.ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT, which is supposed to be subject to the millisNoReAdd (as opposed to SetPolicy.SET_ALWAYS, which is not subject to it).

Comment: are you deleting it from cache before  or after the change on datastore?
Are you using a sychronous or asynchronous way for the deletion?

Comment: @JoséSoní I'm doing the putAll/deleteAll process AFTER storing to the datastore and I'm using synchronous putAll/deleteAll.